# How to jumpstart on html5 JavaScript migration for struts based UI?

Tags: javascript, html

I am not a specialist in UI/UX design and hence pardon my knowledge in this space. My team is however tasked to move away from Struts. And the platform of choice is JavaScript with html5. Now the questions that I have are around the tools and best practices people use towards the following:

1. What IDE do you use?
2. What is the equivalent of JUNIT for unit testing both?
3. Any well known test automation platform (selenium?)
4. Web server technologies
5. Build and deployment tools
6. Sites where I can refer to for all of the above

Comment: This isn't my area but seeing a numbered list of questions, I'm thinking these should probably be separate questions or this may be flagged as too broad.

Comment: Migrating away from a solid Java MVC solution like Struts to a server-side JavaScript nightmare?  Oof, my condolences.